# Method with a NullPointer Exception

Tags: android

Using sharedpreferences I run this method:

```
private Button button1;
private Button button2;
private TextView textView1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
checkIndex();
```

// here save preferences if there are not
// after second start of program, checkIndex(); goes to that crash

```
public void checkIndex(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PRIVATE_PREF, 0);
    String index = prefs.getString("scelta", "");
    if (index == ""){
 index();
    }
    else {

        String scelta = prefs.getString("scelta", "");
        int a = prefs.getInt("arraystart", 0);
        int b = prefs.getInt("arrayend", 0);

        int size = prefs.getInt(prog +"_size", 0);
        String prog[] = new String[size];
        for(int i=0; i<prog.length; i++)

         prog[i] = prefs.getString(prog + "_" + i, null);

        String titolo = prefs.getString("titolo", "");
        int x = prefs.getInt("x", 0);

        textView1.setText(""+a+" "+b+" "+titolo);
```

I've a NullPointer exception by `textView1` and I don't understand why! (I spent many many hours but nothing)... why? thanks!

logcat:

```
11-30 21:49:42.806: E/AndroidRuntime(3739): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 21:49:42.806: E/AndroidRuntime(3739): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.perledisaggezza/com.example.perledisaggezza.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 21:49:42.806: E/AndroidRuntime(3739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
11-30 21:49:42.806: E/AndroidRuntime(3739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-30 21:49:42.806: E/AndroidRuntime(3739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-30 21:49:42.806: E/AndroidRuntime(3739):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-30 21:49:42.806: E/AndroidRuntime(3739):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-30 21:49:42.806: E/AndroidRuntime(3739):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-30 21:49:42.806: E/AndroidRuntime(3739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-30 21:49:42.806: E/AndroidRuntime(3739):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 21:49:42.806: E/AndroidRuntime(3739):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-30 21:49:42.806: E/AndroidRuntime(3739):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-30 21:49:42.806: E/AndroidRuntime(3739):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-30 21:49:42.806: E/AndroidRuntime(3739):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-30 21:49:42.806: E/AndroidRuntime(3739): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 21:49:42.806: E/AndroidRuntime(3739):     at com.example.perledisaggezza.MainActivity.checkIndex(MainActivity.java:480)
11-30 21:49:42.806: E/AndroidRuntime(3739):     at com.example.perledisaggezza.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:149)
11-30 21:49:42.806: E/AndroidRuntime(3739):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-30 21:49:42.806: E/AndroidRuntime(3739):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-30 21:49:42.806: E/AndroidRuntime(3739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-30 21:49:42.806: E/AndroidRuntime(3739):     ... 11 more
11-30 21:51:08.107: E/Trace(3796): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: Can you post a full logcat?

Comment: Also, you can't compare strings with ==, use .equals() or check for length being 0.

Comment: Ok I will modify (but for now works), thanks.

Comment: did you initialize `textView1` ?

Comment: So line 480 is  `textView1.setText(""+a+" "+b+" "+titolo);`? Where is textView1 initialized?

Comment: sure! In the main textView1 works perfectly (I also add the inizialize code in method by I've same crash).

Comment: textView1 initialized is here: public class MainActivity extends Activity { private TextView textView1; and after "onCreate" I've textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

Comment: `R.id.textView1` exists in layout of the activity?

Comment: After "onCreate" I've a textView (textView1), with 2 buttons I can go previous and next (using an array). Works. Does not works using this method...

Comment: then in given scenario `NPE` not possible at you mentioned line. Try you Project clean > Run again > and check weather the crash came on same line or not.

Comment: clean done... nothing... same error...

Comment: what this line is doing `prog[i] = prefs.getString(prog + "_" + i, null);` change it with `prog[i] = prefs.getString(prog + "_" + i, "");`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20415/discussion-between-pol-hallen-and-m-mohsin-naeem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `checkIndex()` **before** doing `textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);` You need to first initiatlize textView1 then you can work with it, otherwise `checkIndex()` is working with a null reference. Therefore, you need to add `textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);` before `checkIndex()`;

Comment: Then you need to post your whole code, you're giving us incomplete information.

Comment: No problem! next time though, post the whole code, you left us wondering exactly what went where.

Comment: also I show "titolo" correctly using toast, but no using the textview (I see "null"). If "titolo" is correctly saved on savedpreferences, why I can see by toast but no using textView1?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your onCreate(...) method. It seems that you did not write

```
setContentView(R.layout.some_layout_file)
```

that contains a TextView with textView1 id. OR you should use

```
TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)
```

Comment: I re-check: I've same code (textView1 after onCreate runs, crashes when starts checkIndex();)

Comment: You did not initialize textView1. You add your layout, then go to checkIndex() method without initializing textView1. Use this line at the begining of checkIndex(): `textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)`